# HTTP ERROR 500 keep showing up with my php coding

Tags: php, web-services, web

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['ccode']) && isset($_POST['mobile'])){

    // Authorisation details.
    $username = "stravin123@gmail.com";
    $hash = "eb88119d3e9cdc20634c62f6493644ff94dec1b60597f68459becfb7ae0a7e96";

    // Config variables. Consult http://api.txtlocal.com/docs for more info.
    $test = "0";

    // Data for text message. This is the text message data.
    $sender = "Visitor Management Team"; // This is who the message appears to be from.
    $numbers = $_POST ['ccode'].$_POST['mobile']; // A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
    // 612 chars or less
    // A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers
    $message = urlencode($message);
    $data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.txtlocal.com/send/?');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // This is the result from the API
    if($result ==true){
        echo "Message has been sent";
    curl_close($ch);

    }
?>
```

This is my php code. Whenever I try to access it, it keep showing HTTP ERROR 500. I am currently using hostinger. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: check your logs

Comment: you're using POST and a GET method, why?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace. I'd suggest using a good IDE with syntax and error checking to catch issues like this in the future.

Comment: @aynber True... or it's a bad paste.

Comment: Try removing the question mark from the url

Comment: @RamRaider `/send/?` - Right, unless they're asking what should go there *lol!*

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace! Works fine when you add the final closing curly brace. `Message has been sent{"balance":4.45,"batch_id":504887624,"cost":1.11,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"VMSYS","content":"big ol t****es swingin in the breeze.... this has a questionmark too"},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"1688245416","recipient":367946793629}],"status":"success"}`